# Umbraco, memory. How to find the cause?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, memory, umbraco

Since two weeks we have a problem with one of our websites, in „rush hours” (Analitycs shows ~170-200 people in real-time) it consumes all available memory (16GB).  Normal state is between 2-3GB allocated. Memory growth isn’t constant, sometimes is very rapid, like 4-16 GB/2 min, another time growth is gradual. This behaviour looks the same on both of our servers (Server1 and Server2).

Server configuration:

Traffic between public internet and the actual application servers is being handled by haproxy, currently all traffic is directed to Server1, if Server1 stops responding traffic goes to Server2 (active –backup configuration). Website database (MSSQL 2008 R2) is placed on Server3. On Media server we store all files from application virtual /media folder. That server is powered by Linux and no problems here.

Server1, Server2, Server3 are VMs placed on one physical machine (Linux Debian KVM,  latest version of libvirt from backports, machines are rock-stable, especially the DB Server). Media server is a physical storage machine.

Server1:

- OS – Windows Server 2012 Standard
- CPU – 8x2GHz
- RAM -16GB
- IIS8

Server2:

- OS – Windows Server 2008 Web
- CPU – 4x2GHz
- RAM – 4GB
- IIS7

Common things for both servers:

Site is based on Umbraco 4.7, .net 4.0. Media folder is connected as „network location”
physically placed on Media server (Linux Samba 3.x). In database we have about 25000 nodes.

We observed that website intensively use connection with Media server (up to 200Mbit/s).

We have changed the URLs so that media requests no longer pass through IIS.
Website was moved beetwen Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012, yet the problem remains.

We thought that problem lies in the code, so we rolled back all the changes since last month (using our code repository), that didn’t solve the problem though.

We already have used programs such as DebugDiag and Ants Memory Profiler

http://imageshack.us/a/img823/8151/p4performancemonitor.png
http://imageshack.us/a/img838/2319/p4tasks.png

How else can we check where the problem lies?

Comment: Do you have use ProcessExplorer to see what application is "eat" that memory ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add an image. Memory was consumed by w3wp.exe process.

Comment: Do you use web garden ? (more than one working process for the pool that runs your app)

Comment: No we don't use web garden? Should we?

Comment: No, with web garden the run is more complicate, needs a lot of synchronizing and easy to lost resource and memory. The other way to look is on plugins, maybe you have any plugin that is not so good ? In general to me is seems that the program is forget to close some resource - hard to locate that stuff. The Ants Memory Profiler, that you use can give you more infos, work with it a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to check for that I've used when I've had memory issues in the past with Umbraco sites:

1) Is the site using Linq 2 Umbraco in the code anywhere? This has quite a few problems with memory usage, especially under heavy load, so it's possible that this could be the cause of your problems. If you are using it, look at your code for inefficient Linq queries, and consider replacing the code with something using the Node API or XSLT instead.

2) Is the site running any custom .net code that uses the Document API on the front end? In general this can be pretty slow and resource intensive, and should be avoided if possible on the front end (back office is fine).

3) Check any other custom code for potential memory leaks or inefficient use of resources.

4) Have a look through the old issue logs for Umbraco (can't find a link at the moment, sorry!), that should give you an idea of whether you're experiencing a known issue with that particular version of Umbraco. If it is, you may need to upgrade (which may or may not be a major hassle depending on your Umbraco setup).

Hope that helps!